# Why predicted values differ in knn regression when using caret vs FNN?

Tags: regression, k-nearest-neighbour, caret

I was trying to do some manual calculations of knn regression and came across this unusual error. The predicted values done by hand do not match with the ones I got from the 'knnreg' function in the 'caret' package. So I used another package (FNN) as a second check and discovered that my manual calculations do agree with the ones from the FNN package. So I'm really confused now. Here is an example code:

```
# caret  vs. FNN packages
# issue in predictions

library(caret)
library(FNN)

n <- 100

x <- rnorm(n)
y <- 2 + 3*x + rnorm(n, sd = 0.5)

x <- as.matrix(x)

# using caret
knn_caret <- knnreg(x, y, k = 5)
yhat_caret <- predict(knn_caret, newdata = x)

# using FNN
knn_FNN <- knn.reg(train = x, y = y, k = 5)
yhat_FNN <- knn_FNN$pred

# manual calculation using the neighbors.
# choose a point
i <- 3
nn <- kNN(x, k = 5) # get nearest neighbors for point 'i' (using the caret package)
neighbors <- nn$id[i, ]

mean(y[neighbors]) # manual calculation

yhat_FNN[i]  # FNN package

yhat_caret[i] # caret package
```

If you can point to any mistake that I may have made in my code or any thoughts on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with the way you've coded the caret and FNN models. For knn_caret, you build the model and get the predictions in two separate steps. For knn_FNN, you are using the predictions from the training step, and the 5 nearest neighbours used to calculate the prediction *exclude* the sample itself. For knn_caret, where you predict in a second step, the 5 nearest neighbours *include* the sample itself, as it is also in the training data.

If you change your knn_caret training data to exclude point 3, then the prediction for point 3 should match both your manual calculations and the FNN prediction. e.g. run something like this:

```
knn_caret <- knnreg(as.matrix(x[c(1,2,4:100)]), as.matrix(y[c(1,2,4:100)]), k=5)
predict(knn_caret, newdata=x[3])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  It makes sense now.  @Lynn, is it the case that we can not get in sample predictions using caret?  Or is there a different way to get predicted values for the all training points in the caret knnreg function?

Comment: @userK, from a quick look at the caret package I can't see a way to do this (but I'm not that familiar with it so there could be something I've missed). One way you could derive these values is to use a 6 nearest neighbours model, then re-calculate the predictions to remove the point itself. Using the 3rd point as an example: $(yhat\_caret[3] \times 6 - y[3])\div 5$.

Comment: Thanks, let me try your suggestion.